# Is it possible to create a multilingual site JUST with HTML, CSS and jQuery?

Tags: multilingual, frontend

I would really appreciate some light on this. Got a new assignment and client doesn't want to use Wordpress or any other CMS (and I can't code PHP, Ruby etc).

Would it be possible to build a functional multilingual site from scratch, with just front end coding?

If not, what would you advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having `/language/` at the start of your urls, e.g. `/en/` for the english version, and `/nl/` for the german (or whatever code you use). You will have to translate all the pages by hand.

In the past, I have had some success with a customer who "didn't want a CMS" by setting everything up in a CMS (which I didn't tell them about), then saving all the rendered pages. They got what they asked for, how I did it isn't relevant to them. Make sure you file off the serial numbers.

Comment: haha yes I know. It's a shame though, to do everything by hand just seems crazy! Which CMS did you use by the way?

Comment: Joomla, mostly because that's what I was most familiar with. I've since started work on a CMS which will spit out a static site (but it is not usable yet, sorry).

Comment: I thought of doing this with AngularJS. Am looking at tutorials now to see how it could be made.